# Signals from delegate

Tags: c++, qt

I started working on a project that requires the using of the TableView. My table has 3 columns and the last column has a comboBox. Using the Delegate I managed to set the comboBox and to retrieve a signal when the index status of the comboBox changes. The problem is I can not identify from witch comboBox the signal is emited from.

If I signal to the mainWindow the QString of the comboBox this seems to be very bad. I was thinking at a solution  to insert into the comboBox from each line the index of the row. Something like row + name.

I initiate the connection using the advice from another post, such like:

```
signals:
   void boxDataChanged(const int & str);
```

In create editor:

```
QComboBox * editor = new QComboBox(parent);
    editor->addItem("This");
    editor->addItem("is");
    editor->addItem("nice");

    connect(editor, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SIGNAL(boxDataChanged(int)));

    return editor;
```

And called like:

```
connect(mydelegate, &Delegate::boxDataChanged, [=](const int & str)
 {
        qDebug() << str;
 });
```

This is working nice but I also need to know from witch row this is comming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is I can not identify from witch comboBox the signal is
>   emited from.

You can use [`QObject::sender`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to get the sender of the signal.
It will return a `QObject` that you can cast into the desired type.